# CLLocation Manager (How Change AlertView Message)

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager

How to change the Message,which is displayed while we try to use user current location

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out `purpose` on [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html):

> If the value of this property is non-nil, the system includes the
>   string in the dialog that asks the user whether it is all right for
>   your application to use location services. The string gives you a
>   chance to explain the reason for why your application is using
>   location services.